# Ranking web app, how to connect result from created result to chosen in form player

Tags: node.js, ejs

this is my first post here.

To gain a experience I made web app for my friends from board games geek group. We play a tournament, it is something similar to the board game league.
In my web app you can Sign up/login and add your game score, check other players game score, and future you will be able check the league ranking(here I have small problem). For this moment my problem is:

- when a logged-in player creates a game result, it only applies to the player who adds the result.
  how to make it connect with the player he chooses from the form.

I have no idea how to do it.
any suggestion. similar topic will be helpful

first step is **creating new result**

```
router.post("/", middleware.isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
var ktoG= {               \\ player 1 current logged user
    id:req.user._id,
    username: req.user.username
};
var kto= req.body.wynik.kto; \\ opponent player chosen from list of registered users
var wygral= req.body.wynik.wygral; \\ the player who creates the result, mark who won the game
var stronnictwo= req.body.wynik.stronnictwo;
var opponent= req.body.wynik.opponent;
var base= req.body.wynik.base;
var round= req.body.wynik.round;
var token= req.body.wynik.token;
var created= req.body.wynik.created;
var author = {
    id:req.user._id,
    username: req.user.username
}
var newWynik = {ktoG: ktoG, kto:kto, wygral: wygral, stronnictwo:stronnictwo, opponent:opponent, base:base, round:round, token:token, author: author}
Wynik.create(newWynik, function(err, newlyCreated )
    {if(err){
        console.log(err)
    }
    else{
        res.redirect("/wynik")
    }
}):
```

});

**mongoos Schema**

```
var wynikSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
ktoG:{
    id: {
        type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User"
    },
    username: String
},
kto:String,
wygral:String,
stronnictwo:String,
opponent:String,
base:String,
round:Number,
token:Number,
created:{type: Date, default: Date.now},
author:{
    id: {type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User"
    },
    username: String
},
comments:[
    {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref:"Comment"
    }]});
var Wynik = mongoose.model("Wynik", wynikSchema);
module.exports = Wynik;
```

**here is part of form to create new result.**

```
 <form onsubmit="return isValidForm();" action="/wynik" method="POST">
<p class="hidden">Logged Player</p>
 <select class="hidden" name="wynik[ktoG]" >
    <option value="logged user">current user</option>
</select>
<p>Opponent?</p>
<select name="wynik[kto]" >
<% user.forEach(function(users){ %>
<% if (users.username===currentUser.username) { %>
    <option class="hidden"><%= users.username %></option>
 <% } else { %>
    <option><%= users.username %></option>
 <% }}); %>
</select>

<p>Chose your side?</p>
<select  class="stR" name="wynik[stronnictwo]" onchange="val()" >
    <option  value="Rebels" >Rebels</option>
    <option  value="Empire" >Empire</option>
</select>
<p>Chose oponennt side?</p>
<select class="op" name="wynik[opponent]">
    <option class="opR" value="Rebels">Rebels</option>
    <option class="opE"  value="Empire" selected>Empire</option>
</select>


<p>Today game win?</p>
<select  name="wynik[wygral]" >
    <option value="Win" >Win</option>
    <option value="Loos" >Loos </option>
</select>
<button type="submit" id="button" >Submit</button></form>
```

**form route**

```
router.get("/new", middleware.isLoggedIn, function(req,res){
    User.find({}, function(err, alluser){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        else{
        res.render('wynik/formul', {user: alluser});
        }
    })
});
```

**Post edited**

**this is my app.js.**

```
    var app             = express();
var bodyParser      = require("body-parser");
var cookieParser    = require('cookie-parser');
var flash           = require('connect-flash');
var path            = require('path');
var mongoose        = require("mongoose");
var methodOverride  = require("method-override");
var Wynik           = require("./models/wynik"),
    passport        = require("passport"),
    LocalStrategy   = require("passport-local"),
    Comment         = require("./models/comment"),
    User            = require("./models/user"),
    session         = require("express-session");
require("dotenv").config();


// requiring routes
var commentRoutes   = require("./routes/comments"),
    wynikRoutes     = require("./routes/wynik"),
    indexRoutes     = require("./routes/index");
    mapRoutes       = require("./routes/map");




mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/wyniki_v4", {useUnifiedTopology: true,
useNewUrlParser: true,});

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
app.use(flash());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(methodOverride("_method"));


// ==============================
    // Passport config
// =================================?
app.use(require("express-session")({
    secret:"aron lubi muchy",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());


app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.locals.currentUser = req.user;
    res.locals.error = req.flash("error");
    res.locals.success = req.flash("success");
    next();
});


app.use(mapRoutes);
app.use(indexRoutes);
app.use("/wynik", wynikRoutes);
app.use("/wynik/:id/comments/", commentRoutes);


app.listen(3001, function(){
    console.log("serwer aktywny");
});
```

**In my project I use few libraries.**

- "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
- "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
- "cookie-parser": "^1.4.5"
- "ejs": "^3.1.2",
- "express": "^4.17.1",
- "express-session": "^1.17.1"
- "method-override": "^3.0.0",
- "mongoose": "^5.9.13"
- "passport": "^0.4.1",
- "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
- "passport-local-mongoose": "^6.0.1",

**Other**
I use MongoDB, NodeJS.

here you can find all code.
https://github.com/Mic-Ko/rebellion

thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Welcome. Please add tags and more information in the post about your technology stack and libraries being used.